# How do i get expiration date from private key on pem format that generated from certificate?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, pem, certificate-expiry

Hi i generate 2 file from the certificate

1. This one in `.pem` format, generated using
   `openssl pkcs12 -in {{key_pair_file}} -out {{file_name}}.pem -nocerts -nodes -password pass:test`
2. This one in `.cer` format, generated using `openssl pkcs12 -in {{key_pair_file}} -out {{file_name}}.cer -nokeys -nodes -password pass:test`

So how to know the expiration date of the **number 1**?
actually I already use `openssl x509 -noout -enddate {{file}}.pem` command
but got an error.

```
...PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:...:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys don't have any inherent notion of expiration.  Only certificates do.